# Best way to apply function with many iterations to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply a text replacement with conditions to a pandas series with many different iterations. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

MY first though would be to define a function, iterate within the function and then apply that, however this will obviously not work due to only returning one value per row (the first iteration only):

```
def numberreplace(x):
    matches = {'FIRST':'1ST',
               'SECOND':'2ND',
               'THIRD':'3RD',
               'FOURTH':'4TH',
               'FIFTH':'5TH',
               'SIXTH':'6TH',
               'SEVENTH':'7TH',
               'EIGTH':'8TH',
               'NINTH':'9TH',
               'TENTH':'10TH'}
    for key in matches.keys():
        if (' '+key+'' in x) or (x.startswith(key)):
            x = x.replace(key, matches[key])
            return x
        else:
            return x
data['STREET REFORMAT'] = data['STREET REFORMAT'].apply(numberreplace)
```

Another idea I had would be to define a list outside of the apply statement, iterate over the list of dictionary keys and then apply the function to the row with the list element, however, I am not certain on how to apply a multi-parameter function to a series and also specify which parameter is the 'row' parameter of the series.

```
def numberreplace(row,k):
    matches = {'FIRST':'1ST',
                   'SECOND':'2ND',
                   'THIRD':'3RD',
                   'FOURTH':'4TH',
                   'FIFTH':'5TH',
                   'SIXTH':'6TH',
                   'SEVENTH':'7TH',
                   'EIGTH':'8TH',
                   'NINTH':'9TH',
                   'TENTH':'10TH'}
    if (' '+k+'' in row) or (row.startswith(k)):
        row = row.replace(k, matches[k])
        return row
    return row
    
    nummatches = ['FIRST','SECOND','THIRD','FOURTH','FIFTH','SIXTH','SEVENTH','EIGHTH','NINTH','TENTH]
    for match in nummatches:
        data['STREET REFORMAT'] = data['STREET REFORMAT'].apply(numberreplace(match))
```

What would be the most effcient way to run this apply function over a dataframe with many rows and many replacement strings?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to return x inside the for loop, you need it only once, after the loop ends. Try this:

```
def numberreplace(x):
    matches = {'FIRST':'1ST',
               'SECOND':'2ND',
               'THIRD':'3RD',
               'FOURTH':'4TH',
               'FIFTH':'5TH',
               'SIXTH':'6TH',
               'SEVENTH':'7TH',
               'EIGTH':'8TH',
               'NINTH':'9TH',
               'TENTH':'10TH'}
    for key in matches.keys():
        if (' '+key+'' in x) or (x.startswith(key)):
            x = x.replace(key, matches[key])
    return x
data['STREET REFORMAT'] = data['STREET REFORMAT'].apply(numberreplace)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to rewrite the function is with regex:

```py
import re
def numberreplace(x):
    matches = {'FIRST':'1ST',
               'SECOND':'2ND',
               'THIRD':'3RD',
               'FOURTH':'4TH',
               'FIFTH':'5TH',
               'SIXTH':'6TH',
               'SEVENTH':'7TH',
               'EIGTH':'8TH',
               'NINTH':'9TH',
               'TENTH':'10TH'}
    for key in matches.keys():
        x = re.sub(re.compile(f"\s*{key}"), matches[key], x)
    return x
data['STREET REFORMAT'] = data['STREET REFORMAT'].apply(numberreplace)
```

This will replace any occurrences of the `keys` with the equivalent `matches`, and return your original string if no matches are found. This solution is about 2x faster than the one utilizing the `string.replace()` method, so it might be useful for your large dataframe with many rows and many replacement strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, you can create two conditions and do a `mask` with your dictionary `matches`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"STREET REFORMAT":["FIRST", "THIRD", "IAMNINTH", "EIGTHISME"]})

cond1 = data["STREET REFORMAT"].str.contains("|".join(fr"\b{i}\b" for i in matches))
cond2 = data["STREET REFORMAT"].str.contains("|".join(fr"^{i}" for i in matches))

print (data["STREET REFORMAT"].mask(cond1|cond2, data["STREET REFORMAT"].replace(matches, regex=True)))

0         1ST
1         3RD
2    IAMNINTH
3     8THISME
Name: STREET REFORMAT, dtype: object
```